# socket.io streaming binary data

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have just started using node.js, I'm running a node server with sockets.io and i need to send a buffer of bytes to the client.

I understand that this can be done by first translating the byte buffer to base64 and sending that, then translating it back on the client side. but i was wondering if there is a more elegant way of getting the byte stream to the client.

Comment: I think this is a valid answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24617425/950039. Kindly Tick if satisfied, comment if not :)

Answer (score 4):

Socket.IO 1.0 Now supports Binary data transfer. Please have a look [here](http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#binary) . You can use Blob, ArrayBuffer and File.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs can be a solution. base 64 have ~30% of overhead size, so if you need to transfer large amount of data it will become inefficient.

Comment: I have looked at binaryjs but i cant find a way of making it work with my socket.io server. I don't want to scrap the code i have written already.

Answer (score 2):

There is also socket.io-stream https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-stream

Comment: Project looks like it's no longer active. i.e. issues are not getting resolved.

Answer (score 1):

It is little difficult to use binaryjs with socket.io.
Try deliveryjs

> https://github.com/liamks/Delivery.js

which provides the means of communication between clients and server via socket.io.

However this module also uses the base64 conversion, which is a drawback.

Comment: That link does not help at all.