# Send logs to web page with node.js

Tags: node.js, stream, docker

I have an issue while trying to send some logs of my app to the front.

I want to send all the logs of a specific docker container to a web page. I can attach it into the console it works perfectly but I can't manage to send this stream to a simple webpage that will displays what is happening into the container.

How can I do that ?

I already tried to use socket.io but I always get a Circular JSON error, and all I can get to the front end is a [object Object] and nothing else.

Here is the function I use to attach my container :

```
docker.containers.attach(containerId, {logs: true, stream: true, stdout: true, stderr: false, tty: false}, function(err, stream){
  stream.pipe(process.stdout); //This shows what happens inside the container. I want to send this output to a web page
})
```

Comment: take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228274/socket-io-streaming-binary-data you can't emit binary with socket.io unless there you use `base64` but in that question there are some good links.